# Email copy of filled-out Google Form including boilerplate

Tags: google-forms

I have constructed a Google Form used to book a community hall, and the form includes some Terms and Conditions that the user is agreeing to.  I've displayed the Ts&Cs using the description field of a Section Header.

I've found some scripts that let me email the submitted data to our administrator to process the booking, and to the submitter so they have a copy of what they submitted.  But I really want both emails to include a copy of the Ts&Cs that the user has agreed to.  It's important for the user to have a record of what they've agreed to.  And since they could change over time, we need to know which version each user has agreed to as well.

Is it possible to access the Section Header contents from a script when the form is submitted so I can include it in the email? It looks like the FormResponse object doesn't give you access to the headers. Or can anyone suggest an alternate way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked about "an alternate way to solve this problem", I suggest using a required checkbox question with only one option: namely, the text of terms and conditions. This is more in line with the industry practice which requires a user to explicitly check a box next to T&C. The full text of this option will be included in the response, and can be emailed to the user by a script running on form submission.

One drawback is that options do not support line breaks. But one can separate sections with some ASCII art: I used 58 `=` signs below. This sort of formatting, replacing line/paragraph breaks with ===, can be done automatically if the document is long; the result is then copy-pasted into an option. The email-sending script can reformat the text for email, say, by replacement `str.replace(/={2,}/g, '\n')`.

Using a part of Stack Exchange terms of service for illustration:

[image: terms]

I don't know what the maximal length of option text it, but it can be *long* (multiple screens to scroll).

Answer (score 0):

My solution should be to use the autoCrat add-on from  New Visions Lab.
With this add-on you can add a PDF document to an automated mail you send to the user.
See: http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/add-ons/autocrat

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't help me extract the Ts&Cs from the form.  I can already add send emails to the user and add any content I want to those emails, but I can't add the specific Ts&Cs the user agreed to.  E.g. say a user opens the form, then I update the Ts&Cs, then the user submits the form:  they will have agreed to the *old* Ts&Cs, but the email would contain the new ones.  I need to be able to capture the content of the form.